# How to hide content behind a password UIAlert? Xcode

Tags: uiviewcontroller, hide, uialertview

I have an `UIAlert` to prompt for password when the App is launched but I want to hide the content from the viewcontroller when the password is required, specially when in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.
Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may do so by placing an object such as UIImageView or even a simple UILabel on top and settings it's alpha to 1.0 when password is required. You may even consider applying a UIAnimation for fade-in/out effect for a better user experience:

```
-(void)setupLabelForContentHiding{
    CGRect rect = labelEmpty.frame; //UILabel
    rect.origin.y = 0;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    rect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;    
    labelEmpty.frame = rect;
    labelEmpty.alpha=0.0;
}

-(IBAction) hideContent:(id)sender{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];

    labelEmpty.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```